# Replacing observations by NA if total number of observations in a year is not enough

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)
Company_1 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Company_2 <- c(8, 9, NA, NA, 10, 11, 12, 13)
data <- data.frame(Year, Company_1, Company_2)
```

For each year, I want to have the number of non-NA observations:

```
data %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise_all(funs(N = sum(!is.na(.))))
```

As can be seen, in Year 2000, company 2 only has 2 observations. The requirement: only consider the data on the year if the total number of observation in this year > 2.

Therefore, I want to replace those two observation by NA.

Company_2 will become:

```
Company_2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Would you mind please spending some time to suggest some solutions for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a custom function and calling it in the `summarise_all`:

```
my_check <- function(x) { # custom check function
  if (sum(!is.na(x)) > 2){
    sum(!is.na(x))
  }
  else{
    x[!is.na(x)] <- NA
    sum(!is.na(x))
  }
}


library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise_all(funs(N =  my_check(.) ))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
Year Company_1_N Company_2_N
<dbl>       <int>       <int>
1  2000           3           0
2  2001           4           4
```

Data:

```
Year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)
Company_1 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Company_2 <- c(8, 9, NA, NA, 10, 11, 12, 13)
data <- data.frame(Year, Company_1, Company_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf`: The inner query extracts the Year wise Company data and sum it. And then on this summarize data, we can check if the `sum>2` then consider it else set it to `0`.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Year,
      case 
      when a > 2 then a # IF COUNT OF Company_1 > 2 THEN CONSIDER THE VALUE 
      else 0            # ELSE SET IT TO 0
      end a,
      case 
      when b > 2 then b # IF COUNT OF Company_2 > 2 THEN CONSIDER THE VALUE 
      else 0            # ELSE SET IT TO 0
      end b
    from (select Year,count(Company_1) as a,count(Company_2) as b from data group by Year)")
```

Output:

```
  Year a b
1 2000 3 0
2 2001 4 4
```